# OS-independent parallel for loop in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, operating-system, multiprocessing

**Goal**

I am trying to make a multithreaded for loop in C++, something like

```
std::vector<int> X;
for_parallel ( int& i : X )
{
  // The code in here will be run in parallel for each 'i'
}
```

**My confusion**

I am getting lost as there seems to have a whole bunch of possible ways of doing such thing and some seem to be system specific. [Parallel Patterns Library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Patterns_Library) for example is build by Microsoft so I would expect it to eventually work only on Windows. I still tried to install it via homebrew on my Mac OS but I failed so I suppose it indeed it only work on Windows. I am asking for some help to figure out what method I should be using.

**Question**

I am planning to run my code on both MAC OS X and Linux, so I would need a solution that would work on both OS (or that is very easy to modify and recompile). Can you please suggest a package that would help me out (and eventually provide a simplistic example of such "for_parallel" loop)?

Comment: Have you looked at OpenMP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenMP or Intel TBB. They can work cross-platform and have parallel-for functionality.

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously consider [c++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11), it is very portable, look at the [std::thread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/) reference.

I have used this library on win32 / win64, linux and macOS -- You probably can not get much more portable than that.